# Undefined react method with ES6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6 to define methods in a React component.

```
class RootContainer extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange)
  }

  handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
    this.props.update_width(window.innerWidth)
  }
  [...]
```

I'm mostly using the ES6 syntax so that I don't have to bind my method in my constructor. This code works just fine, unfortunately, whenever I try to build my app, I get a nice `handleWindowSizeChange is not defined - no undef`

How am I supposed to define it ?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange())`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi That won't work. You need to pass a function reference as a listener instead of calling the function immediately.